# Why are lenses needed for Google Cardboard?

Tags: google-cardboard

Can't the app include computation correction for the image displayed to a standard retinal distance?  For that matter why not "correct" the image displayed per the "optics" of each user?  One could use a little bit of existing hardware (eg: a bluetooth touchpad) to take the graphic inputs needed to define a "corrective/computational" reverse-Amsler grid.
Just a newbie here w/ a question and perhaps a vision/application well before VR. thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a programming question.

Comment: I, too, had an off topic google cardboard question related to the lenses. After several downvotes and a reminder that this is a coding forum, I wondered, where shall we post these non-coding questions? Or is this a question for the meta site?

Comment: @mightypile Probably superuser.com, the SE site for general HW & SW Q&A.

Answer (score 4):

The lenses are needed so you can focus on the screen when it is so close to your eyes.  Moving the device further away isn't the best option, in part because it reduces the available field of view.

Answer (score 1):

From [oculus documentation](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-render/):

> The lenses in the Rift magnify the image to provide a very wide field of view (FOV) that enhances immersion

The lenses allow for a wider field of view keeping the screen size small at the same time. 
See [this YouTube video](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-render/) for a very interesting insight.